# Another Macro works only in debug step mode question

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, commandbutton

Good day everyone!

I've been slowly teaching myself on utilizing vba and after some brief success, have ran into a slight issue.

I have two command buttons, one inserts a new row and populates 4 cells in row 8 while copying the number and formula formats of the row below it (one cell each for date and time, and two fixed text cells).  the second button only populates one cell with time once it is selected.

Both macros work as intended when debugging step by step, however when they are ran via the command buttons, I get a code execution has been interrupted failure.

When debugging the `Range("A8:H8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents` line is usually yellow highlighted however on occasion the `Rows(9).EntireRow.Copy` is.  I'm certain that there is something extremely simple that I am overlooking considering the simplicity of the code involved.

I have attempted to rewrite the lines based off of various posts both on this website and others, without success.

Below is the entirety of the code I have, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Abyssal Chart").Rows(8).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

Rows(9).EntireRow.Copy

Rows(8).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

Range("A8:H8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents

Range("A8").Value = Date

Range("B8").Value = "'T6"

Range("C8").Value = "'Electrical"

Range("D8").Value = Time

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Range("E8").Value = Time

End Sub
```

Comment: You should qualify all your Ranges to make sure the code works on the right sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert Row

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRow()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Abyssal Chart")
        ' Insert new row.
        .Rows(8).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        ' Copy formulas and number formats from row below.
        .Rows(9).Copy
        .Rows(8).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ' Clear contents but 'preserve' formulas.
        .Range("A8:H8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        ' Write to new row.
        .Range("A8").Value = Date
        .Range("B8").Value = "'T6"
        .Range("C8").Value = "'Electrical"
        .Range("D8").Value = Time
    End With
End Sub

Sub InsertTimeStamp()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Abyssal Chart").Range("E8").Value = Time
End Sub
```

**Module where the command buttons are e.g. `Abyssal Chart`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    InsertRow
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    InsertTimeStamp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 for the clarification.  that being said I'm receiving an interruption error using your code with the application.CutCopyMode= False being highlighted yellow.

Comment: It's still working on my end, but you can safely remove it since you are afterward writing to the worksheet. Does this take care of the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not... considering it's working on other computers just fine, I'll have to assume it is a setting or situation on my computer that is causing the issue that hasn't been brought to light yet as it looks like it isn't the code

Comment: Did you try the "wait"-statement (see below)? The difference between your setup and those of the other contributors seem to be your data. Could you please give additional information, e.g. number of columns, value or formula content, ...?

Answer (score -1):

Your script works fine in my Excel environment.

If you did not change anything when running the macro several times and the error occurs:

- occasionally
- at different statements
- but not while debugging,

I would assume that Excel did not finish one statement before it starts with the next.

Usually this happens to me, when I run a batch script over a large amount of data, when lots of cells feature formulas that have to be updated or when I adjust charts.

When this happens to me, I usually put in a little delay and see if the error does still occur.

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

In your case, you could start putting the statement between "Rows(9)..." and "Rows(8)..."

```
Rows(9).EntireRow.Copy
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Rows(8).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
```